# Blender render issue: rendered images are different from viewport

Tags: rendering

[image: evee]
Hi guys.

Can anybody help with this issue? Want to render a circle filled with Voronoi texture and two modifiers but the final render is really different than the viewport render and I want the look in the viewport. Using Evee and same render samples for view and final.

Cheers TORArtist

Comment: Hi. The question provides few information.That can be subdivision surface settings with different values for viewport and render. If not, you can upload your file here using: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: hi lemon 46 it´s uploaded :-)

Comment: After uploading, you'll get a link that is to be pasted here in your question or in comment...

Comment: oh yeah sorry: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=xyaNzn1g" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/xyaNzn1g/)

Answer (score 1):

Subdivision surface and screw have two different parameters for rendering and the viewport:

[image]

So to fix it, set render to 3 for the subdivision and render steps to 3 for the screw.

Comment: Changed the subdiv to 3 and still dont get the triangular shape I see in the vireport :-(

Comment: Change the screw too!!

Comment: The screw is a three as I want it

Comment: But in you file, for the screw, the "render steps" value was 16. Set it to 3 too. Have a look at what I've surrounded in green in the picture above.

Comment: Oh yes - Thanks a lot :-)